# react native navigation useFocusEffect triggered before goBack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

I use react-native-navigation and redux. I have a Stack Navigator with two screens.

The second screen uses some data stored in redux by the first screen.
The first screen has a function that resets that data inside a useFocusEffect hook so when the focus is back on the first screen all the data will be erased.

```
// First Screen

useFocusEffect(
   useCallback(() => {
      dispatch(clearAllData());
    }, []);
);
```

The problem is that if I try to go back to the first screen using navigation.goBack() somehow the data is cleared before the second screen is completely unmounted and it throw an error.

```
// Second Screen
const some_params = useSelector(state => state.data.some_params);

// error: can't read property "some_params" of null
```

I tried adding a little timeout on the dispatch(clearAllData()) and it worked but I don't think it's a valid solution.

I can use the optional chaining like state?.data?.some_params but I will have to use it everywhere.

Is it possible to trigger clearAllData being sure the second screen is completely unmounted?

**Edit**

I've tried both useIsFocused and navigation.pop() but none of them works as expected.

Finally I found a solution using InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions

```
useFocusEffect(
  useCallback(() => {

    const task = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      dispatch(clearAllData());
    });

    return () => task.cancel();

  }, [])
);
```

Comment: could you try navigation.pop() instead of goBack

Answer (score 1):

Can you try clearing data like this

```js
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const focused = useIsFocused()

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(focused){
            dispatch(clearAllData());
        }
    },[focused])
```